# Why does the validation performance have large fluctuations during deep CNN training?

Tags: validation, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, training-data

I´m training a deep CNN for a binary classification problem, and the classes are distributed 50% in the training, validation and test partitions. I have lack of data and hence use various regularization methods (data augmentation, dropout, weight loss, early stopping). I use the optimizer *Adagrad* with default parameters.

A plot from a training run is shown in the following image:

[image: Chart]

You can see that the validation accuracy is jumping between 50% (random guess) and values more close to the training curve, or in between. I am interested in any hypotheses to why the validation performance behaves like this.

**Note**: This is not a question about over-fitting which I am familiar with, but rather a question on why the validation performance in this case has fluctuations of this pattern.

Comment: and how do you compute the validation accuracy? Is this on the **whole** validation set? If so - how big is it?

Comment: Validation accuracy is the accuracy over the validation set. The data is partitioned 70/15/15% randomly into train/validation/test

Comment: And how big is the whole set? In other words - how many samples fall into 15% bucket? 15% sounds like a tiny amount, I would expect at least 20% to fall into testing, and for small dataset (<10K examples) even 30%. If your dataset is in hundreads you cannot even use a single split.